# Mapping Python list values to dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a list of rows...

`rows = [2, 21]`

And a dictionary of data...

`data = {'x': [46, 35], 'y': [20, 30]}`

I'd like to construct a second dictionary, `dataRows`, keyed by the row that looks like this...

`dataRows = {2: {'x': 46, 'y': 20}, 21: {'x': 35, 'y': 30}}`

I tried the following code, but the values of `dataRows` are always the same (last value in loop):

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    for key, value in data.items():
        dataRows[row] = value[i]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is connection between `data` and `rows`? Because if you are hopping to connect them by insertion order you will have troubles because dictionary orders items by hash value.

Comment: The position of the row corresponds to the position of the value in the data dictionary. So, in other words, if row = 2 (position = 0), its corresponding values are x = 46 (position 0) in data['x'] and y = 20 (position 0) in data['y'].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not puting sub-dictionaries inside dataRows. The fix would be this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    dataRows[row] = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        dataRows[row][key] = value[i]
```

Comment: *EXACTLY* the same code (including whitespace) I put in my answer (not posted because you posted first).

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Also, take note of using collections.defaultdict() which allows you to avoid assigning dict to every iteration (post below)

Answer (score 2):

Following code works for me:

```
rows = [2, 21]

data = {'x': [46, 35], 'y': [20, 30]}

dataRows = {}

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
  dataRows[row] = {}
  dataRows[row]['x'] = data['x'][i]
  dataRows[row]['y'] = data['y'][i]

print dataRows
```

UPDATE:

You can also use collections.defaultdict() to avoid assigning dict to dataRows in every iteration.

```
import collections

rows = [2, 21]

data = {'x': [46, 35], 'y': [20, 30]}

dataRows = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
  for key, value in data.items():
    dataRows[row][key] = value[i]

print dataRows
```

Answer (score 0):

In a line:

```
>>> {r: {k: v[i] for k, v in data.items()} for i, r in enumerate(rows)}
{2: {'x': 46, 'y': 20}, 21: {'x': 35, 'y': 30}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python 3 solution with only one explicit loop:

```
{r: dict(zip(data.keys(), d)) for r, *d in zip(rows, *data.values())}
```